Update tikz style of a named node type to be a box with two colours
Right now I have a node type that looks like this (pictured with wires coming out):

but I'd like it to just have two colours -- white on the left and orange on the right (no shading). I've read about clipping and pics and seen many solutions on how to draw a box with two colours or circle with two colours.
In my case, this node is already in many tikzpictures in my document, and it doesn't seem like anything I've read will help me update the style file to produce what I'm looking for.
Right now the node is defined in the style file as follows:
\tikzstyle{shadedSquare}=[left color=white, right color={rgb,255: red,245; green,124; blue,0}, draw={rgb,255: red,245; green,124; blue,0}, shape=rectangle, thin, minimum size=8pt, inner sep=0pt]

and used, for example, as follows, throughout many tikz files:
\node [style=shadedSquare] (mySquare) at (0, 1) {};

Is it possible to add style options to get a two-coloured node? An alternative I'm considering is making the node a plain orange square, and then writing a script to go through all my tikz files and add code to draw a half white rectangle on top of each of these. This seems bulky though.

I'd start by looking for an easier method but, if not, I'd just create a custom shading which did what I wanted. I'd show you with an example, but you've not provided any code to play with. Off-topic: note that you shouldn't be using \tikzstyle as it's been deprecated for a long time. Use \tikzset instead.

Please add a small example so that we know in which context you use this style. You can use path picture={\fill[orange](path picture bounding box.south) rectangle (path picture bounding box.north east);} which leaves the right half of a shape in orange. This, just like a shading, does not rotate with the shape.

Would a pic element (a kind of node) be a solution for you?
